# CHM Reader for Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, chm

What are my options for a viewer for Microsoft Help "CHM" (aka Compiled HTML) files on Mac OS X? I'd like to use a more recent program than [Chmox](http://chmox.sourceforge.net/), which was last updated on February 5th, 2005.

Answer (score 3):

do you try [iChm](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/28171/ichm)?

Answer (score 3):

### [ChmPages](https://apps.apple.com/in/app/chmpages/id1164062917?mt=12)

---

In 2021, I have found [ChmPages](https://apps.apple.com/in/app/chmpages/id1164062917?mt=12) in AppStore and it is really useful to read Compiled HTML Help (.chm) and MIME HTML (.mht, .mhtml) files. I liked the simple UI especially the bookmark management feature which allows you to access and manage the bookmarks of the document.

Along with that, it can do the following:

1. Search and Find
2. Navigation

   1. Show the Home Page
   2. Next/Previous Page
   3. Show/Hide Sidebar
3. Manage Bookmarks
4. Printing Document

It contains the QuickLook plugin to get an idea of document content without actually opening it.

> I wish it could convert the CHM to PDF and comes with a dark theme.

To know more about the ChmPages visit their [official website](http://www.mitledas.com/chmpages/).

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Tubby](http://bluecouch.com/tubby/) (version 0.6.3, updated 2006, Bluecouch Software), [Chimp](http://www.google.com/search?q=chimp+sphera) (version 1.1, updated 2005, Sphera Software), and [xchm](http://xchm.sourceforge.net/) (version 1.13, updated 2007, GPL).

Yes, they're all somewhat obsolete, and I wasn't happy with any of them.

Instead, I now use [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) (version 0.7.15, Kovid Goyal, updated August 2010). Calibre will import my chm files and export them as PDFs, which I find much more usable.

Comment: This is not a CHM Reader. pity I can't vote it down :( vote me up so that I can vote you down!

Answer (score 1):

"CHM Viewer Free" is quite good. Rated 4+ on the Mac App Store.

Version 5.1.0 is from 2013.

Features tabs, bookmarks, fullscreen, search on page and in whole file, and more.

https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/chm-viewer-free/id650683226?mt=12